# Apache Solr suggestion suggest only if search term have missing last char

Tags: search, solr

I'm having very strange issue with Broadleaf solr search please see following screen-shot
 [image]

here is i search with wrong spelled term "mesur" then solr search provide spell correction result but see result all results seems to have last char missing.

now see following second screen-shot
[image]

now i have appended "e" to search terms and its "mesure" now then it is not providing any results can any one having good solr experience help me out with this especially why solr have missing last character in suggestion?.

Comment: please share youer schema.xml and part of solrconfig.xml for /suggest request handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by changing schema.xml, i'm having issue with field type, previously it was as follow

```
<fieldType name="text_general_partial" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />

            <!-- Partial Word matcher -->
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3"
                maxGramSize="1000" />
            <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3"
                maxGramSize="1000" />
            <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" />

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

but i have changed to as follows and it's working fine now

```
<fieldType name="text_general_partial" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />

            <!-- Partial Word matcher -->
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3"
                maxGramSize="1000" />
            <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3"
                maxGramSize="1000" />
            <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
             language="English" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" />language="English" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

removed filters as per xml schema and its working fine now